# Error running script on Mac OS but runs ok after ssh

Tags: ruby, macos, cordova, ssh

I have a .sh script on a Mac OS machine to generate an IPA file using PhoneGap. If I log in the machine via ssh, and then run the script, it runs successfully. But if I try to execute it remotely, by doing an ssh and calling the script as below:

```
~$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/mykey admin@IP_ADDRESS 'cd /Users/admin/scripts && ./build.sh'
```

Then I get this error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- xcodeproj (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from generate_scheme.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

I have this on the beginning of the .sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=$PATH:/bin:/usr/bin:Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin:/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/bin:/Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/admin/.rvm/bin:/Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/xcodeproj:/Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby

export PATH
```

And this is the line that is failing:

```
ruby generate_scheme.rb
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Does the script depend on any environment variables? Where are those environment variables set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ssh by default establishes a non-login shell and therefore does not pick up whatever environment settings are in place for that user. Specifically, on your system it does not pick up settings for `xcodeproj`.

Use `bash --login` to establish a login shell:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/mykey admin@IP_ADDRESS -t 'bash --login -c "cd /Users/admin/scripts;./build.sh"'
```